# Create dummy variables if value is in list

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I'm working with the Zomato Bangalore Restaurant data set found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/himanshupoddar/zomato-bangalore-restaurants). One of my pre-processing steps is to create dummy variables for the types of cuisine each restaurant serves. I've used panda's `explode` to split the cuisines and I've created lists for the top 30 cuisines and the not top 30 cuisines. I've created a sample dataframe below.

```
    sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['Jalsa', 'Spice Elephant', 'San Churro Cafe'],
        'cuisines_lst': [
            ['North Indian', 'Chinese'],
            ['Chinese', 'North Indian', 'Thai'],
            ['Cafe', 'Mexican', 'Italian']
        ]
    })
```

I've created the top and not top lists. In the actual data I'm using the top 30 but for the sake of the example, it's the top 2 and not top 2.

```
top2 = sample_df.explode('cuisines_lst')['cuisines_lst'].value_counts().index[0:2].tolist()
not_top2 = sample_df.explode('cuisines_lst')['cuisines_lst'].value_counts().index[2:].tolist()
```

What I would like is to create a dummy variable for all cuisines in the top list with the suffix `_bin` and create a final dummy variable `other` if a restaurant has one of the cuisines from the not top list. The desired output looks like this:

| name | cuisines_lst | Chinese_bin | North Indian_bin | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jalsa | [North Indian, Chinese] | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Spice Elephant | [Chinese, North Indian, Thai] | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| San Churro Cafe | [Cafe, Mexican, Italian] | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: For `Spice Elephant` why is `Chinese` 1 but `North Indian` 0 when both are present?

Comment: @ifly6, that was a typo. I have updated the question. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the dummies, then reduce by duplicated indices to get your columns for the top 2:

```
a = pd.get_dummies(sample_df['cuisines_lst'].explode()) \
    .reset_index().groupby('index')[top2].sum().add_suffix('_bin')
```

If you want it in alphabetical order (in this case, Chinese followed by North Indian), add an intermediate step to sort columns with `a.sort_index(axis=1)`.

Do the same for the other values, but reducing columns as well by passing `axis=1` to `any`:

```
b = pd.get_dummies(sample_df['cuisines_lst'].explode()) \
    .reset_index().groupby('index')[not_top2].sum() \
    .any(axis=1).astype(int).rename('Other')
```

Concatenating on indices:

```
>>> print(pd.concat([sample_df, a, b], axis=1).to_string())
              name                   cuisines_lst  North Indian_bin  Chinese_bin  Other
0            Jalsa        [North Indian, Chinese]                 1            1      0
1   Spice Elephant  [Chinese, North Indian, Thai]                 1            1      1
2  San Churro Cafe       [Cafe, Mexican, Italian]                 0            0      1
```

It may be strategic if you are operating on lots of data to create an intermediate data frame containing the exploded dummies on which the group-by operation can be performed.